# Time to spread the word

Tags: discussion

We're in public beta, now we need to let people know that we are here.

To get things started I've done a post for the GitP Worldbuilding forum:
http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?374474-Worldbuilding-Stack-Exchange

I had a quick read of the forum rules there and it seems that post should be allowed. (We don't want to spam people or post in inappropriate places as that will just annoy people, not get them interested)!

Comment: I did a similar thing on my school forum, but that's private (no link)

Answer (score 5):

I like the fact that you've included direct links to interesting questions, in addition to the link to the site. I would expect there to be many people who aren't motivated to browse an unfamiliar site but will click on a link to an intriguing question. I recommend anyone who is ready to share a link have a glance at the [top voted questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) for examples of eye catching posts.