# Creating an ad for community promotion

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One of the ideas for promoting the site was creating a [Community Promotion Ad](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/311/81) for another site. But if we want to do that we need a banner to post. This banner needs to advertise our site in visual manner. So, to decide on the best banner to represent a site, post the banner here. If you have multiple banners, please post each of them in separate answer.

Here's the required format:

> **Image requirements**
>   The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
>   Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
>   Must be GIF or PNG No animated GIFs
>   Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
>
> All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
> > `[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]`
> >
> > `[1]: http://image-url    [2]: http://clickthrough-url`

On a normal site where we post the actual answer, that's all that's allowed, but here it's ok to post some discussion if you're doing it on this post.

The click through link should be to this site. We could have it go to the unanswered section, but that is almost always empty so I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: Good point about the unanswered section.

Comment: Are multiple votes ok?

Comment: @ivy_lynx vote on everything you have an opinion on.  We aren't necessarily picking just one anyway.

Comment: As part of this, please also think about site-specific ads (and label as such), if there's some approach that would particularly suit RPG or Writers or Physics.

Comment: I have an idea but no graphical skills, so I'll throw it out here in case anybody likes it and wants to run with it: a person at a drafting table with a mostly-complete world map, books piled next to him, and a couple of white mice observing.  (The mice are just an "in joke" for those who know; they shouldn't be the point of the ad, just an extra touch.)

Comment: I'm thinking that when a post gets six upvotes (enough to get it posted as a community ad if it were posted as a community promotion ad), I'll move it over to several community promotion threads.

Comment: I've changed the background images of my ads due to copyright issues, the changes are not too drastic, but significant none the less.

Comment: Do we have any architects or people who know architects? I'd like to see a blueprint drawing of a planet as the logo. I think it would work.

Comment: @DannyReagan That would be an amazing logo. Not just community promotion ad but logo. Though for a logo we have to wait for a bit.

Comment: What, no suggestion as of yet that says **HELLO WORLD** ?!?

Comment: Also, I can't believe I didn't actually see this meta post until just now... I blame caching.

Answer (score 13):

[image: World In Progress]

Comment: I like this one a lot.  The blue planet is nice too, but this conveys "building up from the bare rock".  Also, it's compatible with building non-earth-like worlds, for that extra alien touch.

Comment: This one has hit six votes. If you would like you can post this on some community promotion ad threads on other sites, overactor. Or I can do it, your choice. Or you can do some and I can do some. :D

Comment: @DonyorM post it whereever you see fit. I can't for the time being.

Comment: @overactor it's time for a new round of ads and Stack Exchange has changed the size requirements a little.  Would you be able to make a version of this that's 300px wide by 250px high so we can run it on other sites?  If so please post it as an answer to [this meta question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2899/28).  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[image: World In Progress]

Comment: I think this is my favourite out of teh one's I've made so far.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Worldbuilding.SE]

Comment: Check [this version](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/339/253) for alternate colors on the text. I prefer this one, but I got suggestions by overactor and TimB for those.

Comment: The font isn't great - perhaps try something simpler

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: Damn, there's 4 I really like now :)

Comment: Alternate color version: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/340/253

Answer (score 4):

[image: World In Progress]

Comment: I like this, but could you bump up the contrast on the text a bit?  The dark-ish blue is kind of hard to read against the black-ish background.  Maybe one of the brighter blue shades in the planet would be better?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've bumped up the contrast a bit, does it need more?

Comment: It's better with the contrast bumped, I'd still like to see a version of this one with the hazard tape idea though :p

Comment: That's better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Worldbuilding.SE]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Worldbuilding.SE]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Worldbuilding.SE]

Comment: Are the two "o"s in "noone" intentional? BTW, I thought this was a good one, but apparently someone else disagrees

Comment: @DonyorM well, it's supposed to be "no one" - I guess I should re-export it with proper spelling xD

Comment: That's better. :D

Comment: I've downvoted this one and upvoted your other one. I think this one appeals more narrowly, so the other would be a better use of the space.

Comment: "Where no one has gone before" isn't consistent with SE's goal of providing sites where you can get expert answers to your questions.  Experts *have* gone there before -- not *your specific world*, of course, but they've definitely "boldly built".

Answer (score -1):

[image: World In Progress]

Answer (score -6):

[image: What will you build?]

Comment: This *might* be copyright infringement...

Comment: I also can tell what it is. I wouldn't know what site this was for if it was posted as an community promotion ad. Do you want to clarify how it might be copyright infringement?

Comment: It's from the hitchhiker's guide movie, I'm not sure if this falls under fair use. I could add worldbuilders.se at the top or bottom, but I feel like it diminishes the image as a whole.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Literal worldbuilders. Very nice pun, but I'm not sure how many people would get the reference. I agree, there isn't enough space for the worldbuilder text, but I also think its hard to tell what it is without it.