# Creating a large external ad

Tags: discussion

We are already working on [internal adverts to use with the Stack Exchange network of sites](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/creating-an-ad-for-community-promotion). This is limited to 220 by 250 pixels. Would there be interest in also creating a larger advert that people can post externally (outside the Stack Exchange network)?

What we need to discuss:

- **the size of the advert** (it's easier to design for a specific size and shape, even if it may sometimes be scaled elsewhere)
- **external places** where the ad may be acceptable
- any important **points to consider**
- any reasons **not** to advertise externally

If there's a positive response we can post another meta question where the answers are large adverts and anyone who wants to post one externally can (being guided by the votes if they wish).

Comment: It might be in our interest to create several images of different shapes and sizes.

Comment: @overactor good point. I'm interested to see discussion of whether that should be a selection of specific shapes and sizes, or just not specifying and inviting any.

Comment: Having some sense of where these external ads would be used would help.  Other sites may have their own size requirements, after all.

Comment: @Monica yes definitely. Ideally a list of potential places so we can gradually add details to them.

Answer (score 3):

### I think we should create many different images of many different shapes and sizes.

Luckily, the [IAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Advertising_Bureau) has done some work to standardize [web banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_banner) sizes with the following results:

[image: Banners]

I feel like we should adhere to these sizes and possibly make one image (or several images) for each of those sizes, this guarantees that we'll have an ad for most every conceivable use case on the web.

### Some things we'll have to keep in mind

Unlike the [community promotion ads](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/creating-an-ad-for-community-promotion), the target audience of these ads won't necessarily know the philosophy of the stackexchange network. So where these images are used and what context is given to these images should be considered and specified when designing one of those images. I'll leave further comments on this topic to others (or maybe I'll tackle it at some point in the future.)

Comment: This is precisely the kind of definitive guideline we need! Perhaps we could standardise a title for answers to the ad-seeking meta question, with the resolution in bold at the start of the answer.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, these are not actual size. You can select "View image" to see the larger image.

Comment: @githubphagocyte That problem should be solved now, the sizes refer to the outside of the orange boxes of course.

Comment: Yes it's pixel perfect now.