# May (and should) we use the site design on our blog?

Tags: support, blog, design

We have [a blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory).  Its front page looks like this:

[image: blog front page]

That area roughly enclosed by a hand-drawn red circle is space that we can fill with a graphic.  It actually goes wider than this screen shot; Medium likes wide graphics.

(Note: the graphic below the big expanse of white is the graphic for the latest article.  That content changes, and isn't what we're considering here.  This question is about filling the white space.)

We have a gorgeous, wide graphic that says "Worldbuilding.SE" to viewers:

[image: site header]

In the [first post about our design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/brainstorming-worldbuilding-site-design), Kurtis wrote:

> - Are there any ways that the site should visually connect with the medium blog?

Question for SE: may we have permission to use that art in the header for our blog, in conjunction with the Universe Factory name?  And if so, could you provide a copy that doesn't have the questions/tags/etc text?

Question for WB: any objections to doing this?  I'm imagining just overlaying the UF logo on the site-design background, but restyling the UF text is also fine with me if somebody has proposals there.  Besides, I'm planning to ask @ArtOfCode to do the actual work. :-)

Comment: I think the questions/tags/users are just HTML anchors, rather than being part of the graphic

Comment: Presumably.  I couldn't find the image in the page source, so it's probably included by reference and I just don't know what I'm looking at.  If I'd've been able to find it I would have included that version in the question. :-)

Comment: Here's the header image: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-header.jpg

Comment: I was really confused there for a sec... *When did I post that link?!?!!  Oh wait...wasn't me*

Comment: If the community decides to do this, I can give you some decent resolution design resources rather than grabbing images from the site's page source. Just ping me if you need anything. Thanks.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers thanks!  I take it (from your comment in the first design question and this comment) that you're on board with us doing this.  Are you able to grant permission on SE's behalf?  If not, whom should we ask?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't see any issue with the blog using the design assets. We do it for the Twitter and Facebook accounts of other communities.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers when you get a chance, I'd appreciate it if we could get a high-res copy of the main-site poster.  (We're going to use the top part, so the same idea as the top part on the site.  So if you can't send the whole poster for some reason, sending the top quarter or so would suffice.)  Feel free to email it to me if that's easiest for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blog design is good but I would prefer carrying the main site theme over to be blog if we have the option to do so.

Its links them visually and lets be honest...our site design is awesome...

Answer (score 1):

I have no objection in linking the new WB design to the Universe Factory.  I think that kind of cohesion is a great thing to have.